# Exclude inactive users when sending push notifications and send them after they active

Tags: php, laravel, real-time, pusher, laravel-echo

I created a app using `laravel` and app automatically send `real time notifications` via `pusher`. It works perfectly and I used `Laravel Broadcast`, `pusher` and `Laravel Echo` via `toBroadcast` method.

But I need to exclude those notifications from inactive users and send same notification after they logged in to the system.

How can I keep already sent notification in queue untill inactive users logged in ?